# Running CPUminer Solo mining without client dependencies

Tags: cpu-mining

Is there any way we can run the mining script on a client machine without installing required lib-jansson and lib-curl libraries after compiling.

https://github.com/hyc/cpuminer-multi/tree/daemon

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a [static build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_build).

Comment: could you tell me how to do a static build please

Comment: i tried ./configure LDFLAGS=-static
but i get the error msg below

`checking whether libcurl is usable... no
configure: error: Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2`

Comment: how to do static build ?
I got same error

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.